# Google recaptcha for Meteor project

Tags: javascript, meteor, recaptcha

Once I hooked up the google recaptcha to my Meteor project. It worked for a long time, but now I see that it no longer works. When I try to get 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' script, I see the following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_bound' of null
    at obj.addEventListener (zone.js?1497947745594:940)
    at recaptcha__en.js:39
    at recaptcha__en.js:39
    at recaptcha__en.js:411
```

I tried to take the old my code versions where it no doubt worked, but it even no longer works there. I couldn't find anything by google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an error in zone.js is incompatible with new recaptcha update. I just deleted zone.js after research that it isn't needed in the project.